# SH2016 patch config Wiz error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell

I am trying to implement the new Jun patch on SH2016 farm and when I try to run the config Wiz I get an error unable to upgrade [searchAdminDatabase] failed and the reason it’s looking for a user account which was disabled, when I checked the DB owner I noticed all search, profile, Social, state service, sync, Wss_usageapplication DBs are owned by this account, it looks like this account was used to install SHP. All other DB are owned by Farm account.
I tried to change the ownership of these DBs to Farm account in SQL but did not fix the problem. My question is there a way to change the DB owner to continue or I have to install SHP again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should not disable the service account that was used to install SP, this can cause all kinds of issues.  Also it is typically recommended that you use this installer service account to install CUs.  For quick fix, if this is possible,  I'd enable the service account and try the wizard again.

Comment: I totally agreed with you but unfortunately it was installed by someone else and that person used his personal account to install it instead of using a service account. So I am looking for solution to replace this account with a service account if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have changed the farm account from the Central Administrator site as well.

1. Go to Central admin
2. Open Security page and click on Service Account, from the drop down change the farm account to the new account. Run IIS reset and restart SharePoint time job.